# How to Exclude Multiple Values with Respective Sub Values in WHERE Clause - SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-in

I'm trying to exclude certain subvalues from specific values. To be specific, I have a column that corresponds to maintenance locations (i.e. 'A', 'B', 'C'...) and another that corresponds to jobs at those maintenance locations (i.e. '05', '06', '07'...). What I want to do is to exclude certain jobs for certain locations.

For example, let's say that I want all locations **except** locations 'D', 'F', 'R' and I want to **exclude** jobs '01', '02' and '03' from these ones. So the where clause would look as follows:

WHERE NOT (location NOT IN ('D', 'F', 'R') AND jobs IN ('01', '02' and '03'))

Meaning, "don't give me locations outside D, F and R that have jobs 01, 02 and 03 to them.

For some reason this is not working. Does anybody have a solution to this?

Thanks!

Rene

Comment: Try this query

select * from loc
where (location NOT IN ('D', 'F', 'R') 
and jobs  IN ('01', '02', '03')
);

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! Unfortunately this approach in general didn't work but for your information we were able to get it to work by putting this instead in the "Select" clause as follows:  CASE WHEN location NOT IN ('D', 'F', 'R') AND 
        jobs in ('01', '02' and '03') then 'EXCLUDE'
        else 'INCLUDE' 
       END as 'Right_Locations'

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE location NOT IN ('D', 'F', 'R') AND jobs NOT IN ('01', '02', '03')
```

This excludes both locations D/F/R and jobs 01/02/03.

On the other hand, if you want all jobs excepted 01/02/03 in locations D/F/R, then:

```
WHERE NOT (location IN ('D', 'F', 'R') AND jobs IN ('01', '02', '03'))
```